# How to remove the white background of the text?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, office365

In Microsoft Word, when I put a background image and write text on top of it, the text has white background:

[image]

I want to remove this background, so that the text is written directly on top of the image.

I tried to select "text highlight color" -> "No color" and "Shading" -> "No color" but it did not help.

How can I remove this background?

Comment: Is that a text box? You can select the text box and in Design tab, you can change Fill to "No Fill"

Comment: I tried the same in a text box, and it did not help.

Comment: it works for me, can you provide an image of the text box too? I had to set it to No Fill and then it acted transparent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these two options.

1. Highlight the text and press `CTRL` **+** `SPACE`.
2. In the top most bar, select **Design** then towards the extreme end on the right select **page border**. On the dialog box that appears, select **shading** tab. Ensure that **no color** is selected. Then towards the right, there is a drop down, select **text**.

let me know if it helps

Comment: Ctrl+Space worked like a charm! (it also changed the font, but I could then easily change it back). What does it mean?

Comment: Am glad to hear that helped. Thanks for the feedback. `CTRL`+`SPACE` removes character-level formatting (fonts, italics/bold, font size, etc.) but leaves paragraph formatting (indents, line spacing, etc.) intact.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to work (Windows 10 OS), but I went into

> "Borders & Shading" from the borders dropdown menu

and was able to remove the white space behind the letters by choosing the

> "Shading tab" and "No Color" under "Fill & Clear" under "Styles". Apply to Text.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out how to fix this. My table was green & when I typed “Primary” as a header, there was a white box behind that word. Really made the table ugly. Here’s how I fixed it: Highlight the table and click the A with a purple eraser (‘Clear All Formatting’) & that white box behind the text goes away.